# Regex for Number Range 0 - 6 in Increments of .5

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex to validate GRE analytical writing scores, which go from 0 - 6 in increments of .5. For example, (0, .5, 1, 1.5, ...). So far, I have been able to come up with validating all numbers from 0 - 6:

```
^[0-6]$
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are trailing zeros acceptable, or no? For example, 1.0, 0.50

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this regex. It should work: `^(\.5|[0-5](\.5)?|6)$`

Comment: This matches everything in the required range except `.5`.

Comment: @Bryan: Good catch. I modified it.